# Tone Length not Changing

Tags: java, audio

I have an audio program that takes a frequency and plays it, with a specific number of milliseconds. Here is the program that plays it:

```
package instruments;

import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import note.Note;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Instrument {
    int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024;

    public void play(Note note, int millis, SourceDataLine line);

    public static Instrument load(Formula formula) {
        return (Note note, int millis, SourceDataLine line) -> {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[millis * Instrument.SAMPLE_RATE];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                double period = Instrument.SAMPLE_RATE / note.frequency;
                double angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * i / period;
                bytes[i] = formula.get(angle);
            }
            line.write(bytes, 0, millis * bytes.length);
        };
    }
}
```

The Formula type is here:

```
package instruments;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Formula {
    public static final Formula sine = (double angle) -> (byte) ((int) (Math
            .sin(angle) * 127));

    public byte get(double angle);
}
```

Now the problem is, when I enter `1` into the milliseconds parameter, I get a beep that is approximately 1 second long. If I enter a negative number, the code throws a `NegativeArrySizeException` (this is expected). However, if I enter a positive non-one integer (it expects an integer), it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I would like to know why there is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1638
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.write(Unknown Source)
    at instruments.Instrument.play(Instrument.java:44)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)  // Here is where I play the tone
```

Comment: What's the error message/stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace looks like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is in this line:

```
line.write(bytes, 0, millis * bytes.length);
```

You need to remove the `millis *`.  Recall that the length of `bytes` has already by multiplied by that value.

Just to mention - your mixing of milliseconds and seconds is confusing. If I were to enter a 1 for the `millis` parameter I would expect the sound to play for 1 millisecond, not 1 second.

Comment: I do expect 1 millisecond. The thing is, it plays one second, which is bad. Thanks for the answer though, it now works! So the reason `1` made no difference is because 1*n = n, right?

Comment: Basically. If you want to reduce to milliseconds then you need to divide by 1000, e.g. `bytes = new byte[millis  * sampleRate / 1000];`. At 48000kHz sample rate there are 48 samples per millisecond - so 1*48000/1000==48. You're not going to hear that though

Comment: I use 44.1 KHz frequency. I did do the /1000 thing. It works for ms now.